# Integrity Error duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hr_attendance_pkey"

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am using mobile app for sign in  and sign out into the hr attendance.I am accessing the database of postgresql of odoo and saving the data.When I sign in from web application of odoo then I sign out from mobile.Now again I am trying to sign in from web application.It is showing the following error.

Integrity Error

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hr_attendance_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (id)=(114) already exists.

Comment: Check when `save the data`. do not try to save the same records.

Comment: Which mobile app are you using? Please post a download link so that we can review it.